# Does ServiceStack work with .NET 4.5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack, asp.net-4.5

Does ServiceStack work with ASP.NET MVC 5 and .NET 4.5?   Calling the service from my ASP.NET MVC project.  It appears System.Net, Version 5.0.5.0 is called by ServiceStack.Interfaces 3.9.60.0.  I can't find System.Net, Version 5.0.5.0 while looking up references.

Comment: isn't that a job for google?

Comment: I think in the commercial version "All projects have been upgraded to .NET 4.0, except ServiceStack.Razor which is .NET 4.5 to use the latest version of Razor" . The link [version 4 Release Notes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#the-big-refactor-of-v4)    And the   [ServiceStack web site](https://servicestack.net/)